# GraphAware neo4j-to-elasticsearch plugin exclude nodes by properties

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, graphaware

I'm using neo4j-to-elasticsearch plugin in order to index in ES all of my `Decision` nodes with the following configuration -

```
<NEO4J_com_graphaware_module_ES_node>hasLabel('Decision')</NEO4J_com_graphaware_module_ES_node>
```

I need to exclude some of the `Decision` nodes (to be indexed in ES) based on some node properties, for example I don't want to index `Decision` where `decision.hidden` is true. Is it possible to extend my neo4j-elasticsearch to support it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possible with Inclusion Policies, for your use case it would be like :

```
#optional, specify which nodes to index in Elasticsearch, defaults to all nodes
com.graphaware.module.ES.node=hasLabel('Decision') && getProperty('hidden') != true
```

The reference about possible options is here :

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/common#inclusion-policies